# Bootstrap is not loading (Thymeleaf)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The styling doesn't load when having this code:

```
<div class="container">     
    <div class="w-50">  
        <div class="border border-info"> 
            <div><h3 class="font-weight-bold" th:text="${post.title}"></h3></div >          
            <div><span>Category: </span><span th:text="${post.category}"></span></div>
            <div  th:text="${post.content}"></div >
            <div><span>Author: </span><span  th:text="${post.signature}"></span></div >     
            <div  th:text="${#dates.format(post.date, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></div >                   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Having the following code the page loads properly:

```
<div class="container">     
    <div class="w-50">              
        <div class="border border-info" >
            <div><h3 class="font-weight-bold" ></h3></div >         
            <div><span>Category: </span><span ></span></div>
            <div  ></div >
            <div><span>Author: </span><span></span></div >      
            <div  ></div >      
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help what is wrong with the object here?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by the styles do not load?  Are you saying that you are not seeing bootstrap styles being applied or that the stylesheet fails to load?

Comment: The styles are not applied

Comment: How does the link to the stylesheet look like?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably because you are not using the syntax of Thymleaf in order to link the stylesheet.

Try to change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
```